# Put test classes/packages in one test suite

Tags: android, testing

I have several packages where my tests are located:

1. com.example.tests.common - for both phones and tablets
2. com.example.tests.phones - phones only
3. com.example.tests.tablets - tablets only

Now to run tests for phones I need to run tests located in classes from `common` and `phones` packages - two runs. The same for tablets.

I need them to run all tests for tablets/phone in one go. The [example](https://developer.android.com/reference/junit/framework/TestSuite.html) of TestSuite doesn't work for me:

```
 Class[] testClasses = { MathTest.class, AnotherTest.class }
 TestSuite suite= new TestSuite(testClasses);
```

It doesn't work with an error there is no such a constructor for `TestSuite`.

So the questions are:
1. Why it could not work as per example.

1. Are there any other ways to put required classes/packages in one `suite`?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Normally it is better to name test suite packages like `test.com.example.phones`, adding `test.` prefix to the package name. This allows to run, relocate or move all tests very easily in one go. If it is important to care about device-specific tests, another approach would be like `test.phones.com.example` and `test.tablets.com.example`.

While it is also possible to have test suites, these are often redundant. The most frequent test types are running all tests for the package being tested and running all tests available. If the test packages mirror the main packages, such runs can be easily launched from IDE that provides features to run all tests in a folder/package (right click and select "run as Android test" in Eclipse). And during automated builds in the cloud usually all tests must run anyway.

If you have more tests, not a bad idea is to create a separate testing project.

Comment: You didn't answer his question, you told him what the standards are. Don't get me wrong, I agree with you on the package structure.

Comment: Should I add "right click on the package name in Eclipse and select 'run all tests in the folder'?". I have assumed he probably knows.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/junit/framework/TestSuite.html) for TestSuite(Class[]).
2. You can use a variable-argument list:

   ```
   TestSuite suite = new TestSuite(MathTest.class, AnotherTest.class);
   ```
3. Or an array like you previously did, but you have to identify it with a String:

   ```
   TestSuite suite = new TestSuite({MathTest.class, AnotherTest.class}, "Example");
   ```

Comment: There is no, but here is an example they provide https://developer.android.com/reference/junit/framework/TestSuite.html

Answer (score 0):

What I was really looking for is a [TestSuiteBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/suitebuilder/TestSuiteBuilder.html).

Here is what I have now:

```
public class TabletAllTests extends TestSuite {

    public static Test suite() {

        TestSuiteBuilder suiteBuilder = new TestSuiteBuilder(PhoneAllTests.class);
        suiteBuilder.includePackages("<my_package>.test.common");
        suiteBuilder.includePackages("<my_package>.test.tablet");

        return suiteBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

And the same for `PhoneAllTests`